# Components definition in WebStorm with nuxt-components true option

Tags: vue.js, intellij-idea, nuxt.js, webstorm

The nuxt-components are awesome!
But WebStorm have problem with these components definition and showing "Unknown html tag" error. I can not `Ctrl + Click` for moving in.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 3):

It's not currently supported, please follow [WEB-46418](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-46418) for updates